# I lost my ownership to my personal files

Tags: permissions, ownership

I tried to link some files to plex media player and made a mistake when changing rights and ownership. I made a user named *plex* and gave it (not intentionally) all the rights and ownership of my personal files.

Result: I can not longer access my personal files from my normal user name.

What to do?

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `ls -lR` on your home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert `USER` & `GROUP` the owner of `DIRECTORY`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP DIRECTORY
```

Replace this command with your values and run it.

For instance if your personal files are under `/home/pepe/` do `sudo chown -R $USER /home/pepe/`. This would work because `$USER` represents your actual user.

Maybe you need to restart your system to take effect.

Comment: can't get acces to home/pepe

Comment: .gvfs  ijnput output error ????

Comment: Please, copy and paste the *full* output. And *do not* edit it. It would be hard to help you with wrong information.

Comment: chown: access denied to ‘/home/*******/.gvfs’: access denied: thanks for your help

Comment: chown: change of owner frome ‘/home/xxxxxxxx/.thunderbird/zg9jlwhd.default/key3.db’: input/output error

Comment: This morning after a reboot, all rights and ownership are back to normal, despite the error messages. I thought the error messages meant that the instruction did not work, but it did. thank you!